# Adding <tr> <td> within a div with Javascript not showing within the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, append

I have a HTML table as below :

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Reg ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td>VII</td>
            <td>56733</td>
        </tr>

        <div id="addfield"></div>

    </table>    

<input type="button" value="add" id="add_more_fields" />
```

And the jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html = '';
    $('#add_more_fields').click(function(){
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>Steve</td>';
        html += '<td>X</td>';
        html += '<td>87777</td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        $('#addfield').append(html);

    });
});
```

I wanted to add the `<tr>` generated by the javascript to be within the table. but when I clicked the button, the output is shown outside the table ! How can I display it within the 
table ?

[DEMO Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2yBYb/)

Comment: i think you need to give the id to `Table` instead of `Div` [Updated Fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/2yBYb/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because `div` inside `table` is invalid HTML structure. Append row to the table itself.

Also, you are not clearing the string html. Which causes multiple rows.

```
$('#add_more_fields').click(function () {
    var html = ''; //declare string inside function
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>Steve</td>';
    html += '<td>X</td>';
    html += '<td>87777</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/2yBYb/5/)

Comment: One more query...what if I am having more than one table ?

Comment: @Nitish give id/class to table and access it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `tbody` inplace of `#addfield` like,

```
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Reg ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Alex</td>
        <td>VII</td>
        <td>56733</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#add_more_fields').click(function(){
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>Steve</td>';
    html += '<td>X</td>';
    html += '<td>87777</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('tbody').append(html);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsn5X/)

Answer (score 1):

Append Inside table

```
$('#add_more_fields').on('click',function(){
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>Steve</td>';
    html += '<td>X</td>';
    html += '<td>87777</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);//If you have more table then use id for table to append
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a div inside a table. All you've gotta do is put the id on the table and remove the div.

```
<table id='addfield'>
```